# Configure Nginx to accept All Domain

Tags: nginx, configuration, domain-name

I have a server Ubuntu 11.10 with nginx 1.2.1 
Asumme that my domain is : domain.com
Nginx served as a reverse proxy :
redmine.domain.com => point to webrick redmine on port 3000
svn.domain.com => point to apache2 port 8080
domain.com, www.domain.com, and all domain (etc : abc.com, def.com , ghi.com ) => php-fastcgi port 9000

You may wonder why I have to accept all domain (abc.com, def.com , ghi.com ) , yes, this is our service that allow customers to use their domain in our Multi-Tanency App.

But the problem is :
When I use abc.com ( add a record on  file hosts on my laptop) , to  access my server , nginx redirect the request to our redmine . I want nginx to redirect to php-fastcgi like configuration.

here is my configuration on Nginx : (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/)

Redmine

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name redmine.sieuthimoi.vn; 

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;


    location / {
    auth_basic  "Not Allow Here";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            include         /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
```

}

And PHP-FastCgi

```
server {
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /usr/share/nginx/www/site;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name  domain.com  _;
location ~ .php$ {
    try_files       $uri /index.php
    index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www/site$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Note that : domain.com works perfectly.

Anyone please help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: What are the file names of these configs? I'm wondering if nginx is like Apache, and the first server/vhost it encounters becomes the default.

Comment: the redmine config is : redmine.conf
I use the default file for configuring PHP ( multidomain)
Does it matter ?

Comment: "default file" means /etc/nginx.conf? or something else?

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default . I use this file . Is it OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `listen 80 default_server;` in your PHP-FastCGI `server` section.